# How to compile c++ code at runtime (like eval in Python)?

Tags: c++, pipe, system

I'm compiling some C++ code at runtime, which I'm then calling in a sort of plugin system, see also my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393629/how-to-call-dynamic-library-function-from-c) question. What I do is I create the source code, write it to a file, compile that file and write the output to another file. However, this process feels kinda ugly so I was hoping for some input.

```
//Open a file
std::ofstream fout("SOURCECODEPATH");

//Write actual function to file
fout << "extern \"C\" void testFunc(float testArray[]) {\n"
        "    testArray[0] = 1.0;\n"
        "    testArray[1] = 2.0;\n"
        "    testArray[2] = 3.0;\n"
        "}" << std::endl;

//Compile the file, and write the stdout and stderr to PROCESSOUTPUTPATH using "&>"
system("c++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++14 SOURCECODEPATH -o COMPILEDLIBRARYPATH &> PROCESSOUTPUTPATH");

//Read PROCESSOUTPUTPATH (not implemented)
```

Currently it's creating 3 files, *SOURCECODEPATH*, *COMPILEDLIBRARYPATH*, and *PROCESSOUTPUTPATH*. However, I would much rather not have the *SOURCECODEPATH* and *PROCESSOUTPUTPATH* written to the OS, but rather have them used internally. So pipe (?) the sourcecode to the process and get back the output (preferable split into stderr and stdout). What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There is no portable way to achieve that. For linux you can try redirecting the output to `/dev/stdout`. Also how do you expect to run the output? Note that depending on compiler, os and cpu it will be in different binary format. So IMO what you are trying to do is hopeless anyway. The easiest solution would be to compile to dll/so, dump to disk and do dynamic loading via `dlopen` (or equivalent). Also you may want to have a look at JITing with e.g. LLVM (which is a set of tools for that). Although it is rather difficult.

Comment: You are already tying yourself to a particular platform. Why not go all the way and include clang (or g++) in your program? Then you don't need to use files at all.

Comment: @freakish, AFAIK compiler shouldn't matter, as the "extern C" should allow dlopen (or the windows equivalent) to call the function. Currently I'm compiling to .dll/.so (see my other question, which now has a link). Regarding the CPU and OS, as the code is compiled at runtime, they will match and the only thing necessary is a C++-compiler on the host machine. I think including clang/g++ would be much more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Please reconsider what you're doing. C++ and Python are very different languages in very many ways, not least in their build and execution models. It seems *very* unlikely that runtime compilation is the real solution to your underlying problem (which you have not shared with us). Simply put, C++ was not designed to support this, Python was.

Technically, there are [a few solutions for runtime compilation of C++](https://github.com/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/RuntimeCompiledCPlusPlus/wiki), but they require much more management and effort than `eval` in Python. However, they are pretty specialised and, again, unlikely to be a good solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: I realize C++ and Python are very different, it was meant more as a metaphor to get across what I'm trying to accomplish. I want users to be able to modify the program's behaviour at certain well-defined points (the user can implement specific functions), but I need the raw performance as it is a rendering engine. The solution I currently have works as expected and solves my problem, but I would like to get rid of the two temp files.

The link looks interesting. I'm definitely going to have a look at it, although it might be overkill.

Comment: Given that you're expecting your "users" to write C++, I think it's also fair to expect that they might be able to compile their own shared libraries too. Why not just ship a header file for your interface, have users write small and compile small shared libraries ahead of time, then runtime link to whichever is required? I think my point is: why does the runtime compilation matter so much? Let the users deal with debugging and any platform-specific issues. If you're feeling generous, you can give them a template cmake project (or something) and build instructions to help them along?

Comment: Good question, I've left out a lot of details in the original to reduce irrelevant information and simplify the question. I want to allow experimentation and quick iterations, which is why the program offers a (simple) code editor. The code is then read/analysed by the program (so it actually needs the source and not just the compiled library), translated to valid c++ and compiled. These steps sound much more complicated then they are and they actually work like a charm.

Comment: Good on you, not a project I would embark on lightly but I'm glad it's working for you. I apologise that I seem to have underestimated your understanding in my original answer (I thought I was saving a novice from python from world of hurt)