# How to call dynamic library function from c++?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

Currently I'm creating some sort of plugin system. My program writes the code, which is then compiled (see also my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387656/how-to-compile-c-code-at-runtime-like-eval-in-python) question). The resulting (compiled) library is than opened again using `dlopen`. This allows people to program custom functions in the program themselves.

```
//Open the compiled library at the specified path
void* handle = dlopen("COMPILEDLIBRARYPATH", RTLD_LAZY);
if (handle == NULL) {
    std::cout << "plugin not found" << std::endl;
}

//Find the function pointer and cast is to std::function (is this good practice??)
std::function<void(float[])> fun = (void (*)(float[]))dlsym(handle, "testFunc");
if (fun == NULL) {
    std::cout << "function not found" << std::endl;
}

float test[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
std::cout << "calling plugin" << std::endl;
fun(test);

//Output the result of the call
std::cout << test[0] << " " << test[1] << " " << test[2] << " returned by function" << std::endl;

//Close handle again
if (dlclose(handle) != 0) {
    std::cout << "could not close function" << std::endl;
}
```

This works as expected, but also feels sort of hacky and unsafe. I've never done anything like this before, so am I doing anything unsafe here? Also, is there a "better" way to do this (e.g. where I don't have to manage closing the handle again)? Could this be considered portable across OSes?

Comment: You could use a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to avoid closing explicitly.

Comment: `std::function` comes with some overhead; if the type of the function is clear right from the start, I'd rather prefer a raw function pointer instead. As you have the cast anyway, you might let deduce the type by `auto`. And you should prefer C++ keywords (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C macros (`NULL`).

Comment: About naming: I'd give the function pointer the same name as the function in the dll.

Comment: Hm, if it works as expected, maybe better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Theres is `dlclose(void *handle)` for closing a handle. Also prefer `reinterpret_cast` to a raw function pointer, instead of C-style casting to an `std::function`.

`dlfcn.h` with `dlopen` and its friends is POSIX/UNIX API, so it will probably work on Solaris, Linux, *BSD, macOS etc. On Windows the equivalent of `dlysym` is `GetProcAddress` in `<windows.h>`.

Here a is a full article about dynamic loading thal'll probably help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading#In_C/C++

Comment: ... and `dlopen` is `LoadLibrary`.